# Align div elements on page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to align some `<div>` elements on a page.

Current Page: !

Basically I need to center the title in the middle row to the main title. But I'm not sure how to do that. My code:

```css
.our-services-title {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 38px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #101031;
}

.services-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 141px;
  margin-top: 64px;
  margin-left: 170px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.s-list-item {
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%; /* play with this number */
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
}

.s-list-item img {
  width: 98px;
}

.s-list-item div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.service-name {
  font-family: "Hind";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.service-desc {
  font-family: "Hind";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p className="our-services-title">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>

  <div className="services-list">
    <div className="s-list-item">
      <img className="" src={Outsourced} alt="" />
      <div>
        <p className="service-name">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
        <p className="service-desc">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="s-list-item">
      <img className="" src={Compliance} alt="" />
      <div>
        <p className="service-name">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
        <p className="service-desc">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="s-list-item">
      <img className="" src={Bespoke} alt="" />
      <div>
        <p className="service-name">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
        <p className="service-desc">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="s-list-item">
      <img className="" src={Licence} alt="" />
      <div>
        <p className="service-name">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
        <p className="service-desc">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="s-list-item">
      <img className="" src={Training} alt="" />
      <div>
        <p className="service-name">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
        <p className="service-desc">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="s-list-item">
      <img className="" src={Remediation} alt="" />
      <div>
        <p className="service-name">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
        <p className="service-desc">Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "Our Services" and "Compliance Support" should be aligned in same line?

Comment: Yes @kritiz, that's what i want

Comment: for starter change your "Lorem Ipsum Lore' to "Our Services" and "Compliance Support".

Comment: Already done that.

Comment: what about mobile designs? You cannot keep them aligned in the same manner in all screen sizes?

Comment: Mobile design would be different. I'm more interested about the full page design at the moment.

Comment: you can make use of grid, to position it as your requirement

Comment: @andrew99 Your expectations are unrealistic, there is no reason to align the text in that manner, aim for a layout that looks good on all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to align your title with the text in the middle row, using a `justify-content: center` might not be the best thing.

Reason being, the title will be centered based on the length of the title. This means that even if you end up aligning the title `Our Services` with the content in the middle row (using margins / padding), if the title changes or if the web page / application supports language translation, the length of the title would change, meaning the title would no longer be aligned with the middle column content.

An easy way to ensure that the title is always aligned with the content in the middle column is to include the title and the middle column within the same div.

So, the page would be divided into three vertical `<div>`s with grid styling (2 columns and 3 rows), as such:
[Image_Divided_Into_Divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXWra.png)

The code in its simplest form would look something like:

```css
.main-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}
.child-container {
    flex: 1 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 3fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="child-container">
    <div></div> <!-- empty placeholder div for the grid-->
    <div></div>
    <div>image1</div>
    <div>text1</div>
    <div>image2</div>
    <div>text2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-container">
    <div></div>
    <div>Our Services</div>
    <div>image3</div>
    <div>text 3</div>
    <div>image4</div>
    <div>text 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>image5</div>
    <div>text5</div>
    <div>image6</div>
    <div>text6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. How would I go about the mobile version though? Would it be ok to create another html (having everything on one column) and switch between them? or there s any trick i can use?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the margins between each element, which would make the whitespace between each div less.